# scala slick or and query

Tags: scala, slick

my question may sound very banal but I still didn't resolve it.

I have the Products Table implemented like

```
class ProductsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Product](tag, "PRODUCTS") {
  def id = column[Int]("PRODUCT_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def title = column[String]("NAME")
  def description = column[String]("DESCRIPTION")
  def style = column[String]("STYLE")
  def price = column[Int]("PRICE")
  def category_id = column[Int]("CATEGORY_ID")
  def size_id = column[Int]("SIZE_ID")
  def brand_id = column[Int]("BRAND_ID")

  def * = (id.?, title, description, style, price, category_id, size_id, brand_id) <>(Product.tupled, Product.unapply _)
}
```

and its representation in

```
val Products = TableQuery[ProductsTable]
```

How can I implement query equivalent to SQl query:

```
select * from products where( category_id = 1 or category_id = 2 or category_id = 3 ) and (price between min and max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
val query = Products filter { p => (p.category_id inSet List(1,2,3)) && p.price > min && p.price < max }
val result = db.run(query.result)
```

You can use `println(query.result.statements)` to see what query looks like.

**EDIT**:

Answer for additional question. You can make a function for your query that accepts optional min and max values:

```
def getProductsQuery(maybeMin: Option[Int] = None, maybeMax: Option[Int] = None) = {
  val initialQuery = val query = Products filter { p => (p.category_id inSet List(1,2,3)) }
  val queryWithMin = maybeMin match {
    case Some(min) => initialQuery filter { _.price > min }
    case None => initialQuery
  }
  val queryWithMax = maybeMax match {
    case Some(max) => queryWithMin filter { _.price < max }
    case None => queryWithMin 
  }
  queryWithMax
}
```

And then you could do any of these:

```
val q1 = getProductsQuery() // without min or max
val q2 = getProductsQuery(maybeMin = Option(3)) // only min
val q3 = getProductsQuery(maybeMax = Option(10)) // only max
val q4 = getProductsQuery(maybeMin = Option(3), maybeMax = Option(10)) // both
```

and run any of these as needed...

Comment: thanks a lot..it's working, but I've got other problem...is there any way to do the same but with Option values for example for min and max

Comment: You can read more about queries [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html) and in [my blog post](http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html).

Comment: You can put your ids list in as parameter also, of course.. :)